# How to use Hashlib in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hash, hashlib

I'm trying to hash my emails within a DataFrame using hashlib.  Here is my code:

```
import os, teradata, teradatasql
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import hashlib
db = HmkDbms.GetSysCConn(True)

hcode = 'select top 10 from vdk.customer;'

query = db.execute(hcode)
rows = []
for i in query:
    rows.append(i)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

df.columns = [['id','email1', 'purchase', 'type', 'region', 'volume']]

df['email1'] = df['email1'].astype(str)


df['email1'] = df['email1'].apply(lambda x: hashlib.sha256(x.encode()).hexdigest())
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Please let me know how I can fix this error - nothing I've tried is working.

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your dataframe with `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`?

Comment: Sure - but why the attribute error?  My emails have been converted to text, which should work when converting to hash

Comment: That's why I want the data. I'm not sure why either. It's probably some tricky little thing that escaped your notice - it happens all the time ;)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error message using the code you've shown. What pandas version are you using? Are you inadvertently executing code like `df['email1'].encode()`?